# Check the uniqueness of department name

Tags: sql, plsql

I would like to make a procedure that will help me add a new row in the Departments table. I have to insert department_id, department_name, location_id and manager_id. I made this successfully with that code:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE add_depar(
    p_name VARCHAR2, p_mgr NUMBER, p_loc NUMBER) IS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO DEPARTMENTS (department_id,
    department_name, manager_id, location_id)
  VALUES (DEPARTMENTS_SEQ.NEXTVAL, p_name, p_mgr, p_loc);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Added Dept: '|| p_name);
EXCEPTION
 WHEN OTHERS THEN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Err: adding dept: '|| p_name);
END;
```

Now I'd like to check the uniqueness of the department_name, And if the requirements are not done, I would like to make an exception for that. May I ask for your help! I have tried to do this many times, but still not resolved. Please help!

Thanks

Comment: Do you only want to *know* if the name is unique, or do you want to *prevent* non-unique names to be inserted?

Comment: I would like to see if the department name is unique and if there is a department with the same name, then I have to raise an exception and put the new row in a new table - "Error_depart". If there is NOT a department with the same name, then I have to put the row in "Departments" table. I am calling the procedure with that code: add_depar('Media', 100, 1800);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It you want the department name to be unique, then add a constraint/unique index and let the database do the work:

```
create unique index unq_department_name on department(name);
```

You are much better off letting the database do the validation, because the database will ensure consistency for both updates and inserts, as well as multiple concurrent transactions.

Comment: With that procedure I just want to check if there is a department with the same name and if there is I want to put my row in Departments table, and if there is not I want to put my row in Error_depart table. I am calling the procedure with that code: add_depar('Media', 100, 1800); Do you think that I have to create a unique index?

Comment: @Kaloyan . . . If you want the department name to be unique in the table, then let the database do that work.

Comment: I do not want the department name to be unique, I just want to check if there is a department with the same name. For example if there is not a department called "Media", that row should go in "Departments" table, if not it should go to "Error depart" table. I am thinking that I can use "EXISTS", but not sure how can i do it. May I ask for your help please!

Answer (score 0):

Simplest most effective way would be to add a unique index on "department.name" (Like mentioned by @Gordon) and then add a DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX exception. Would look like this -

```
EXCEPTION
 WHEN dup_val_on_index THEN
  [exception handling];
 WHEN others THEN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Err: adding dept: '|| p_name);
END;
```

Comment: Hello again. I managed to do this task. Now I wonder how to do the same thing for the location_id and manager_id. Please keep in mind that location_id is from table "LOCATIONS" and manager_id is from table "EMPLOYEES". Please take a look at my code:

Comment: create or replace procedure add_dep(
                      p_name VARCHAR2,
                      p_mgr NUMBER,
                      p_loc NUMBER
                    )
    is
    begin
        merge
          into departments d
          using (
                select  p_name department_name,
                        p_mgr manager_id,
                        p_loc location_id
                  from  dual
                ) s
          on (
              upper(s.department_name) = upper(d.department_name)
            )

Comment: when not matched
            then
              insert
                values(
                      departments_seq.nextval,
                      s.department_name,
                      s.manager_id,
                      s.location_id
                      );
        if sql%rowcount = 0
          then
            insert
              into error_depa
              values(
              departments_seq.nextval,
                    p_name,
                    p_mgr,
                    p_loc
                    );
        end if;
end;

Comment: Here is the code, because I can not write it as a comment

Comment: How to modify that code using exceptions: when not matched
            then
              insert
                values(
                      s.department_id,
                      s.department_name,
                      s.manager_id,
                      s.location_id
                      );
        if sql%rowcount = 0
          then
            insert
              into error_depa
              values(
                    p_id,
                    p_name,
                    p_mgr,
                    p_loc
                    );
        end if;